# Excel Pivot Table Filters - How to Make One Filter Drop Down Dependent on Another Drop Down?

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, filtering, pivot-table

I have a pivot table with two drop down filters. I want the data in the second drop down to be refined based on the selection of the first drop down.

i.e. If the table stored city/country data and the two filters were Country and City, I'd want the City drop down to only contain cities that are in the Country chosen in the first drop down.
[Here is a screengrab of what I'm talking about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUVRr.png)

Any tips are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this natively. You have to essentially roll your own userform that lets you toggle between displaying all items, and only displaying items that actually have data given the settings of other filters. And that userform also has to have a bullet-proof way of actually changing those filter settings. What's more, it needs to take a very intelligent approach to doing this, given there may be hundreds, thousands, or more items in a PivotField. Simply iterating through them to check their status is waaay too slow, as per my post on the subject at http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/14/filtering-pivots-based-on-external-ranges/

Consequently, pulling this off efficiently - if at all -  is very tricky. I've been working on a commercial add-in to do this (and a lot more besides) for well over two years that is very close to release, and have found it challenging to say the least, because of the interplay between fields. That said, I have done it and will be releasing it soon, if that's any help. But because it's a commercial product, I can't share the code freely I'm afraid.

Here's an example of how it looks, alongside how the native PivotField filter looks. Note the checked "Hide Items With No Data" setting. That does what you want...it suppresses the display of all those things that are filtered out at another filter level.
[image]

...and here's what you see if you put a check in that box:
[image]

As you can see, it's suppressed the display of a whole lot of irrelevant items (the ones starting with 1) because they are already filtered out by another PivotFilter at a higher hierarchy level.